# Is it possible to change position for group of Activity in stack?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a stack of activities **(A - B - C - D)**. At some point, **D** tries to call **C** (using the framework for this).
**Activity C**, in turn, is invoked using the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` (through the Framework). In my application, this activity has `android:launchMode = "singleTask"` in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file. Therefore, activity **D** is destroyed when **C** is launched. **(A - B - Df - C)** -> **(A - B - C)**. The following sentence explains why this happens.

*In case that there is an Activity instance existed in any Task, the whole Task would be moved to top and every single Activity placed above the singleTask Activity will be destroyed with lifecycle.*

Then activity **C** again causes activity **D**. The problem is that activity **D** is recreated. But I need all Activity to remain as they are, without a flipping. But I cannot refuse to call activity **C**, because it is called from a framework that I cannot change.

Is there a way like `Intent.FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but for the Activity group at a time? In this case, for activities **C** and **D**, and keep their order. Or may be another possible solution.